# json: unable to parse this type of json response

Tags: android, json

I know object is like some:`{` and array like some:`[`
But when i do post request api response with,

```
 {"code": 401, "message":"some message     text"}
```

What kind of json is that, I had tried alot to display the message in a textview but none worked meanwhile I'm able to display object response or array... I'm using `Volley` by the way, I had tried also to check

```
If(response.has("message"){
}else{
}
```

And the same check for "code" to switch it to message from string resources
Thanks in advance

HERE THE FULL REQUEST:

```
    private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                if (jObj.has("user")) {
                // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String uid = user.getString("id_user");
                    String uname = user.getString("name");
                    String uemail = user.getString("email");
                    String utoken = user.getString("user_token");
                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(uname, uemail, uid, utoken);
                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            Activity1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }else {
                    JSONObject jOsbj = new JSONObject(response);
                    TextView scss = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginerror);
                    scss.setText(jOsbj.getInt("code"));
                    String errorMsg = scss.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

Comment: please explain your question properly, and what type of json u getting?

Comment: what you are trying to ask...

Comment: post your proper api response to know your issue well !

Comment: Guys please reread i think its clear, the full response posted also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below is the JSONResponse -

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "some message text"
}
```

u can parse it as below -

1. assumming u have url response in Inputstream in then u read it in a stringBuffer buffer as below -

   ```
   StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
   int ch = -1;

   while ( (ch=in.read()) != -1){
      buffer.append((char) ch);
   }
   ```
2. Now simply parse the response from buffer -

   ```
   JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
   String message = jObj.getString("message");
   ```
3. U r extracted message is in string message.

Comment: Thanks Its first time hear about inputstream and buffer i will tray to learn it then try your code

Comment: @H4F: Sure buddy. Happy coding :)

Comment: Not happy at all :/ I added my full request, can you please explain again based on my code so i understand where to put what

Comment: @H4F: lets continue in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99178/json-unable-to-parse-this-type-of-json-response

Comment: OPS! This room is read-only ; only users with 20 reputation can participate

Answer (score 1):

you used

```
 jsonObject jsonobject= new jsonObject("your json string");

 String Code= jsonobject.getString(code);

 String message= jsonobject.getString(message);
```

Comment: No because what is the "your json string" if response hase only code and message?

Comment: simple string json response

Answer (score 1):

**JSON STRING:**

```
{
      "code": 401,
      "message": "some message text"
    }
```

**Now create a seprate class for response:**

```
 public class ResponseDTO{
   int code;
   String message;
    }
```

Now if you are using android studio add following to gradle or if you are using Eclipse you can find jar on link:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
```

**After that  use the following code to parse json string you already have:**

```
String json = "the json you've recieved from server";
        //ASSUMSE YOUR JSON IS NOT NULL
        ResponseDTO response = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(json.toString, ResponseDTO.class);
        if (response != null) {
            if (response.message.length() > 0 && response.message != null) {
                //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT}
                else{
                    //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I read alot about gson for this but still confuses me , speacialy that i may reseave an object if there was no error, plus what you mean by the json you've.....? I only get code and message in this case

Comment: the code and message you recieved from server is json object then it is converted into string

Comment: And if the post response no error( mean no code no message, just another data object) in this case i prase it inside }else{?

Comment: String json = "the json you've recieved from server";
this line means you have received json object from server in a string

Comment: Still didnt understand what to put in String json

Comment: if (response != null) {
            if (response.message.length() > 0 && response.message != null) {
                //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT}
                else{
                    //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT
                }
            }
        }else{
//then you will handle it over here if it is not message or the code
}

Comment: Aha nice, the last one i get it

Comment: String json means the json you received from server

Comment: Or can be json = requestResponse; ?

Comment: So String json = {"code":400, "message":" .."};

yes exactly

Comment: Nice, last question if you dont mind, gson class should be implented or imported

Comment: gson is a library you should add it to gradle then its is imported in code

Comment: sorry its not toString its toString() with brackets

Comment: Tried it but also error maybe i didnt add , .i will tray it when power comes